# angular unit test - controller

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, coffeescript, karma-runner

Well want to make some unit tests for my controller. I already prepared some stuff and everything works fine, except that the scope is not loading properly. In my controller i set a value user, but in my tests the value do not get set.

```
merchantCreateController = ($scope, $location, Users, keyboardManager) ->
    $scope.user= sector: []
```

Now in my unit test i want to test if the user is initialized with that value.

```
define ["controllers/user", "chai", "angular" ,"angularMocks", "app/services"], (directive, chai, angular, mocks) ->
describe "controllers.user.create", ->
    controller = null
    scope = null
    user= null
    sector = null
    location = null
    beforeEach ->
        mocks.module "app.controllers.user"
    beforeEach ->
        mocks.module "app.services"
    beforeEach ->
        mocks.inject ['$rootScope', '$controller', '$location', 'app.services.user', 'app.services.sector', ($rootScope, $controller, _location, _user, _sector)->
            scope = $rootScope.$new()
            scope.user= sector: []
            user = _user
            location = _location
            sector = _sector
            controller = $controller("app.controllers.merchant.edit",
                $scope: scope,
                $location: location
                "app.services.user": user
                "app.services.sector": sector
                keyboardManager: bind: ->
            )
        ]
    it '$scope.user is initialisized', ->
        console.log scope.user
        chai.expect(scope.user).to.deep.equal sector: []
```

any idea why scope.user is not defined, but everything else is in it like the functions that are in this controller

Comment: That looks like it should work (without running it).  Can you isolate it onto a plunker?  Here's one that's already got a controller unit test on it to get you started:  http://plnkr.co/edit/uBwsJxJRjS1qqsKIx5j7?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
controller = $controller("app.controllers.merchant.create",
            $scope: scope,
            $location: location
            "app.services.user": user
            "app.services.sector": sector
            keyboardManager: bind: ->
        )
```

The mistake was that I tested the create controller, but I wrote edit there :P